# What happens if I cancel my account?

Tags: the-secret-world

I like The Secret World. I want to keep playing it. I just don't have time to *right now* because there are so many other games. I want to cancel my subscription so that I save money while I'm playing other games.

- Can I continue to play until the end of the current subscription period I've paid for even after I cancel my account?
- Can I resume my existing account if I decide to come back to the game, and keep the same characters and progress I made in the past?

Comment: With every other MMO I've ever played the answer is Yes and Yes, with a time limit on the second yes in some (rare) cases. I don't see any reason that TSW would be different.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz That's what I suspected. If there's no sourced answer by tomorrow I'll contact support myself and get official answers.

Comment: I haven't seen any official documentation on this, but I *have* seen several games where the second 'Yes' is only good for a year or so.

Comment: Have you tried just going through the process and not finalizing it? Every pay to play MMO I have played lays out the cancellation rules during the process.

Comment: @Adanion I did that before I asked this question. No dice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can play until your current subscription period ends after cancelling - what you're actually cancelling is only the automatic renewal of the subscription.

Your account and characters are very likely to be held for a long time, but there is no guarantee for this in the [Terms of Service](http://www.thesecretworld.com/corporate/tos/EU/english). However, it's very common in MMORPGs to keep accounts for years if not for the lifetime of a game as the only reason to ever expire them is to free up character names.

Comment: I contacted customer support and they confirmed this. They did claim that they would never delete characters: `You also have nothing to worry about regarding your characters and their progress as even if your account is cancelled, their progress will be saved!`

Comment: Is this answer still up to date?